# Function window.alert is not supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, office-addins, office-ui-fabric

- Project: Office Add-In
- Office-UI-Fabric-JS: 1.5.0
- Fabric Core: 5.0.1

I'm getting the error **Function window.alert is not supported**

The 3rd party library I'm using ("DataTables") uses the "alert" API.

Is there a way, other than manually modifying the Javascript in "DataTables", to replace the calls to "alert"

It would be nice if I could have the calls to "alert" be routed to app.showNotification() (this call is provided in App.js; a file that is normally found in the Office Add-in examples found on GitHub)

Comment: Really hard to understand your question without seeing code.

Comment: You should be able to overwrite / set `window.alert` to a custom function that then calls `showNotification`, eg `window.alert = function(){ app.showNotification() }` More than likely would probably need to do this as soon as possible like in `Office.initialize`

Comment: @PatrickEvans:  **Worked** immediately.  THANK YOU!  I was able to display my tables.  One last question.  How do I pass along the text message that was in the alert to the _showNotification_ function?  _showNotification_ does accept parameters.

Comment: Just define the function argument and pass it to showNotification, see the answer i posted to see an example

Comment: @ezG can you share your app.showNotification function/implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overwrite `window.alert` with a function that will pass on the arguments to `app.showNotification()`

```
//if Office supports arrow functions
window.alert = message=>app.showNotification("Title",message);

//otherwise use a normal function expression
window.alert = function(message){
  app.showNotification("Title",message)
};
```

Should probably do this in the `Office.initialize` handler so that it happens as soon as possible:

```
Office.initialize = function(){
  window.alert = function(message){
    app.showNotification("Title For the Notification",message)
  };
};
```

Comment: @ezG If you satisfied with the answer consider to accept it. Accepting Answers: [How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)